# Jquery enable/disable button based on multiple conditions and selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have a button where it can be click only:

- When user select 1 from dropdown, input for (1) is enabled and he must fill input 1 before he can click the update button, or,
- When user select 2 from dropdown, input for (2) is enabled and he must fill input 2 before he can click the update button, or,
- When user select 3 from dropdown, he can straight click the update button.

My best approach is only for disable the button and the inputs, I don't know how to enable it based on multiple conditions above, please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  $(".button-class, .input-1-class, .input-2-class").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrap">
  <select class="select-class">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-wrap">
<label>Input for 1</label>
  <input class="input-1-class">
</div>

<div class="input-wrap">
<label>Input for 2</label>
  <input class="input-2-class">
</div>

<button type="button" class="button-class">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Hi @tom, thank you for your comment. I've read those documentation and still didn't understand. Can you help me code the example, please?

Comment: @stevangeoge You can bind an handler for the change event on your select and your inputs. When an handler is called, you can enable or disable elements according to some values.